# To Create Android Application by using Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android

I want to build an Android Application which uses Google Maps Android API v2. So, I followed the link -[Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_settings_in_the_application_manifest).
Following the steps prescribed in the link, I am able to generate the API key. Further after completing the steps i tried to run the app. I faced following error.

```
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.task/com.example.task.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2142)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2167)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4831)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:257)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at com.example.task.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     ... 11 more
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4656)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     ... 21 more
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
04-05 10:01:56.442: E/AndroidRuntime(6170):     ... 24 more
```

Error might be because of the **com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment** package in the main.xml .
i have **com.google.android.gms** package in my DUT but not able to find **com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment**. How can i know whether this package is in my DUT or not and also what is the solution to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MapFragment` is part of the `google-play-services` library. To use it you need to import the `google-play-services` into your `workspace` and then reference it from your project, you can reed how it's done in the `first 3 steps` of this blog post I wrote:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: I succeed a bit but now eclipse is throwing a new error- "could not connect to google servers". Also i was able to see zoom in/out options in the app but map tiles is not coming on screen. Any idea about this!!

Comment: Now i am able to see the maps on my app. I was using wrong package while generating api key.

Comment: @YugalKothari, great you figured it out, have a nice coding : )