# Error- Could not contact to google servers

Tags: android, google-maps

With reference to previous error 
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831700/to-create-android-application-by-using-google-maps-android-api-v2/15831781?noredirect=1#15831781)

I want able to move one step ahead. But now i am facing two new errors.

```
04-05 14:24:27.156: E/Google Maps Android API(32366): Authorization failure.
04-05 14:24:27.966: E/Google Maps Android API(32366): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
```

This is only important content from my Manifest.xml file

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.task.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.task.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="_MY_API_KEY_GOES_IN_HERE_"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have referred to the link
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598596/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers-even)
[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727992/google-maps-api-v2-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-servers)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13728039/1758149)

Comment: Just a warning, it's usually bad security practice to post your own API key to others to see. I edited the code to remove it.

Comment: Thanks RyPope but that doesn't work for me. Still I am getting the same error. I can see the Zoom in and Zoom out option in the app but unable to see the map content.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all below mentioned points are taken care:
1) Wrong service was enabled. Make sure the "Google Maps Android API v2", not "Google Maps API v2" is enabled and re-generate the API key.

2)  Add the following elements to your manifest. Replace **com.example.mapdemo with the package name** of your application.

3) Use of **correct certificate and key**. Release certificate, which WILL NOT WORK during debugging when you run the app on my phone. You have to use the debugging keystore certificate fingerprint instead.